# No Surname in indian passport and given name is considered as last name in E ticket for an international flight

Tags: tickets, indian-citizens

I have booked tickets for my parents to visit Mauritius for a week and my mom's passport (given name is xxxx) doesn't have surname, so in the e-ticket form her name has been printed as "Mr xxxx". I have spoken to the travel agency and Air Mauritius, but didn't get any information regarding the issue.

**Can anyone please tell me if there might be a problem boarding the flight?**

I am very anxious right now since its their first international flight.

Comment: I would worry about printing a "Mr" for her more than her having only one name.

Comment: Thats my worry too, since I didnt give any last name the system has randomly given her a name which is a title.

Comment: It is not uncommon in certain contexts to use honorific titles with the first name, such as "Mr. Charles" and "Miss Nancy," etc.  The use of titles in air tickets is fairly insignificant.  I've been booked as *CHAPLIN, CMR* and *CHAPLIN, CHARLESMR* without incident (okay, I'm not Charlie Chaplin, but you get the idea).  As long as the name XXXX appears in the passport and they don't get hung up on the fact that *Mr* has been used for a woman, she'll be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Security checkers have a lot of discretion here. I've had my girlfriend board a flight where she was identified as "Mr. Vo", and I've had my name abbreviated to just a first initial. Both times I successfully boarded the plane. They care much more about a valid passport with a matching photo.

Especially if they're flying from India, where not having a surname is a common occurrence, I think they should be fine.