# Is no surname in Indian passport a problem?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, tickets, airports

I have booked a return ticket to Mauritius from Delhi, India for three adults and two children. The passports for the two children, a boy and a girl, have the surname field blank.

So, when booking the tickets through a website, I did not enter the surname of the children, and a popup asked me to confirm that the name I 'entered' is the one in the passport. I clicked 'yes' and booked the ticket.

In the final printout, it came out like this: XXXX Mstr (Child) and YYYY Ms (Child). That is, 'Mstr' and 'Ms' are shown as the first name of the boy and girl, respectively.

Will this a problem at the airline check in counter or at passport control?

Comment: It's common for airlines to ad Mr and Mrs and the like.  For example, if the name is Tom Sawyer, the ticket may say SAWYER, TOMMR.  I would not worry about it if I were you, though I am posting this as a comment rather than an answer because I do not know how staff in India will react if they conclude that the first name has been entered as surname or vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[No surname in my passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38682/no-surname-in-my-passport)*; also see *[Visa issues, surname of father](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65905)* and *[No Surname in indian passport and given name is considered as last name in E ticket for an international flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67580/)*. More loosely related is *[In which countries are the visitor's first name and last name compulsory?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20061)*

Comment: finally faced no problem at the airport. Thanks